# How do I map column names which are located in a separate table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table COLUMNS with column names and an identifier:

```
ID | COL_NAME <- column headers
1  | 'col1'
2  | 'col2'
3  | 'col3'
```

And a table DATA that has the columns named as the ID instead of the COL_NAME:

```
1 | 2 | 3 <- column headers
x | y | z
a | b | c
```

How can I map the values from COL_NAME to the column names from DATA in a query? I don't want to change the actual tables.

e.g.
`select * from DATA [...]`

The final output should be:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 <- column headers
x    | y    | z
a    | b    | c
```

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, you do not.

If you are accessing the database programmatically using a 3rd-party application (i.e. Java, C++, C#, Python, etc.) then you should perform this transformation in that 3rd-party application using two separate queries:

```sql
SELECT id, col_name FROM columns;
```

then

```sql
SELECT * FROM data;
```

And then when you **display** the output from the second query you can substitute the column headers.

---

You could also build that second query using string concatenation to substitute the column names; however, you would need to insure that you are not introducing SQL injection vulnerabilities into your application.

For example, the pseudo-code for a 3rd-party application:

```
results1 = query( "SELECT id, col_name FROM columns" );
sql = "SELECT ";
i = 0;

for ( row in results1 )
{
  if ( i > 0 )
  {
    sql += ", ";
  }
  sql += `"{sql_escape(row.id)}" AS "{sql_escape(row.col_name)}"`;
  i++;
}
sql += " FROM data";

results2 = query( sql );
// output the results.
```

---

If you want to do it entirely in Oracle, then you cannot do it using only SQL; you would need to use PL/SQL to generate a dynamic SQL statement. For example:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_sql VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  v_sql := 'SELECT ';
  FOR row IN ( SELECT * FROM columns ORDER BY id ) LOOP
    v_sql := v_sql || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME( row.id )
                   || ' AS '
                   || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME( row.col_name )
                   || ', ';
  END LOOP;
  v_sql := RTRIM( v_sql, ', ' ) || ' FROM data';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_sql );
END;
/
```

Which would output the query:

> ```sql
> SELECT "1" AS "COL1", "2" AS "COL2", "3" AS "COL3" FROM data
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b366d726c3a323d8e495368d6e6c513b)*

And you could copy-paste and execute it (or use it in a cursor and iterate over the cursor).